# Reading binary files using python3

Tags: python, python-3.6, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a 16-bit binary file in python3 and I'm getting the following error

> out = struct.unpack("h", bytes)
>   error: unpack requires a buffer of 2 bytes

```
import struct
for line in file_read:
    bytes = file_read.read(2)
    out = struct.unpack("h", bytes)
    file_write.write(str(out))
```

any suggestion on where i might be going wrong will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are traversing your file both by line and by byte-characters.

```
for line in file_read:  # read by line
    bytes = file_read.read(2)  # read by character
```

The first seeks newlines (`b'\n'` aka `b'\x0A'`) and may consume an arbitrary number of bytes. This means your reading of byte pairs is likely offset by 1, and possibly at the end of the file.

Read your file only by character pairs. You can use the [two-argument `iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to conveniently do this in a `for` loop:

```
for pair in iter(lambda: file_read.read(2), b''):
    out = struct.unpack("h", pair)
    file_write.write(str(out))
```

In Python 3.8, you can use an [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) as well:

```
while pair := file_read.read(2):
    out = struct.unpack("h", pair)
    file_write.write(str(out))
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this still may raise the same exception if `file_read` is a file containing an odd number of bytes. However, that would be a problem with the input and not a problem with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably `file_read` is empty or gets empty after reading `line` (as @MisterMiyagi noted, reading binary files line by line doesn't seem to be a good idea). So `file_read.read` reads nothing or just one byte. You can verify it by printing `len(bytes)`.